# Get XML structure in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML variable, for ex.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<A>
 <AA>aa</AA>
 <AB>
   <ABA>aba</ABA>
 </AB>
</A>
<B>b</B>
<C>
 <CA>ca</CA>
</C>
```

I want to get a structure of this XML- table with one VARCHAR kolumn:

```
structure (VARCHAR)
--------------------
'A/AA'
'A/AB/ABA'
'B'
'C/CA'.
```

I don't need to get text in node- i need only structure. 
XML variable can be different (i don't know number of nodes, name of nodes, etc.).

Variable @xml can be without ROOT element.

I tried many combinations of .value() or .nodes(), but it didn't works.
Best result give me an operation:

```
SELECT
    grandparent.gname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    parent.pname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    child.cname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('*') AS grandparent(gname)
CROSS APPLY
    grandparent.gname.nodes('*') AS parent(pname)
CROSS APPLY
    parent.pname.nodes('*') AS child(cname)
```

It gaves me 'A/AB/ABA', but if i don't know number of nodes and nodes names, it is useless to me to continue.

Comment: i tried many ".nodes()" combinations, but it didn't work. Best result gave me
    grandparent.gname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    parent.pname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    child.cname.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
FROM
    @xml.nodes('*') AS grandparent(gname)
CROSS APPLY
    grandparent.gname.nodes('*') AS parent(pname)
CROSS APPLY
    parent.pname.nodes('*') AS child(cname)

but i need to know, how level of depth XML variable has (number of depth lvl = number of 'cross apply').

Comment: add what you've tried to the question instead of in comments, it's much easier to read in the question if you format it

Comment: I'm not claiming credit for this but I found it on beyondrelational where this problem is solved. http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10503/xquery-lab-61-writing-a-recursive-cte-to-process-an-xml-document.aspx All you'd have to do is remove the "value" and you'd get the structure. Basically it's using recursive CTE to crawl through the XML structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE to extract the nodes one level at a time. The anchor part extract the root nodes and `query('*')` gets the child nodes for each node found. `exist('*')` is used to filter out the intermediate rows that is created during the recursion. The recursive part does the same as the anchor only it uses the XML provided in `SubNodes` instead.

```sql
declare @xml xml = 
'<A>
 <AA>aa</AA>
 <AB>
   <ABA>aba</ABA>
 </AB>
</A>
<B>b</B>
<C>
 <CA>ca</CA>
</C>';

with C as
(
  select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Structure,
         T.X.query('*') as SubNodes,
         T.X.exist('*') as HasSubNodes
  from @xml.nodes('*') as T(X)
  union all 
  select C.structure + N'/' + T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
         T.X.query('*'),
         T.X.exist('*')
  from C
    cross apply C.SubNodes.nodes('*') as T(X)
)
select C.Structure
from C
where C.HasSubNodes = 0;
```

Result:

```
Structure
---------
B
C/CA
A/AA
A/AB/ABA
```